# magento 2: copy production server to localhost

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, localhost

I copied my whole Magento 2.1 root directory to my local computer. Also exported and copied the database.sql to my local computer.

Then I setup XAMPP and created a db (with same name as db in production) -> imported the database.sql. After that I changed the base-url from Magento 2.1 to `http://127.0.0.1:80/Servercopy/` -> then changed admin uri `admin_grw0o8` to `adminPath`.

When opening url "http://127.0.0.1/Servercopy/" in Chrome it shows me correctly  my Magento 2.1 webshop.

Problem: When openeing url "http://127.0.0.1/Servercopy/adminPath" it shows error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

How can I solve this ?

Maybe when I change xampp hostname '127.0.0.1' to 'mydomain.com' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually change a couple of values in `core_config_data` MySQL table too:

```
UPDATE core_config_data 
SET value = 'http://127.0.0.1/' 
WHERE path IN ('web/secure/base_url', 'web/unsecure/base_url');
```

**NOTE:** The trailing slash after 127.0.0.1 is important!

When done, flush your cache manually. You can do it by deleting `var/carche` folder or by running `php bin/magento cache:flush` from your commandline.

This should work. Now your local copy will open at `http://127.0.0.1/`

Comment: You are a Magician, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Env.php file needs to be changed, too http://newsgento.com/migrate-magento-2-from-one-server-to-another/